Django migrates data, and an error is reported during the migration, but a table appears in the database, what is going on?
I will connect to three MySQL databases, generally connect to the local database, and then test the database, and there is the online database, if I connect to the local database migration model to generate the migration data successfully, but when I connect to the online database, the field is displayed when the data is migrated (it is a failure during migration), but the corresponding table is generated in the online database, and then I use MySQL When I execute the python manage.py migrate command again, it will show that the table already exists, and it stands to reason that these generated tables will not be recognized by Django, how should this problem be solved?
I tried to use --fake to get him to force the endorsement, but it still failed, and now it shows that this table already exists, and deleting the table is not good to delete because of the online database I have a version of Django that is 3.2.3

Can you paste your Django Database settings (without any username/passwords of course)? I'm curious how you switch between the 3 databases, which may hint at the cause of the issue.
I also understand that this may be an old or legacy project, but Django 3.2.3 was released over 3 years ago and isn't a secure version, it's possible documentation you're reading is meant for newer versions or that version just works differently to what you'd expect.

What is the error? Anyway, "then I use MySQL" – In MySQL, schema alteration statements aren't run in transactions, so it's entirely possible a table gets created, but steps after it fail, which requires manual cleanup.

Hello, the three databases have different usernames, passwords, database names, port numbers, etc., when you switch, you just hide the previous configuration, and then open another configuration to perform the migration, of course, this is under the Django framework, and the three databases are all mysql databases

There is also the online database that Chartacter Set this is utf8mb3 but the local database is utf8mb4, of course, in order to verify this, I specially added a database test database, and then migrated the data after the connection, and there was no test database migration failure.

Because I wanted to solve this problem before, it was because I created a model locally and the migration was successful, but after I connected to the online database, I got a 3078 error after the migration, which should be the incompatibility between the referenced column and the referenced column, and the table appeared in the mysql database, but the dajngo-migrations in mysql brench did not appear in the migration record, and Django did not recognize this migration. This is basically all the problem.
